# Using private package classes in Scala repl

Tags: scala

I have several classes that are marked as

```
package com.salil.mypackage

private [mypackage] MyClass{

}
```

However, I would like to use them in a scala repl. I tried using paste: -raw with code like :

```
package com.salil.mypackage {

     val my = new MyClass()
    }
```

but that fails with :

```
<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
```

any way to access these classes in a repl?

Answer (score 1):

You can use them using `:paste -raw` in the REPL without a problem, as you've tried. Your issue is that your Scala is invalid.

This definition is invalid syntax, you are missing the `class` declaration:

```
private [mypackage] MyClass
```

The following is also invalid syntax, because you cannot place vals in the root of a package. You *can* make it work if you use a `package object`, though.

```
package com.salil
package object mypackage {
    val my = new MyClass()
}

scala> com.salil.mypackage.my
res12: com.salil.mypackage.MyClass = com.salil.mypackage.MyClass@56eae567
```

Comment: This works for Scala 2.11 but not for scala 2.10. Anyway to make it work?

Comment: @SalilSurendran No, `:paste-raw` was added in 2.11.